# Trouble when printing an FIFO array

Tags: arrays, c, function, struct, fifo

I'm trying to make an first-in-first-out array, but for some reason certain values in my array are printing 0 instead of the actual value.
So far ive tried to print every value in the code, searching for a reason for that problem, but im pretty much a beginner in C and I don`t know how I can be better at troubleshooting the errors in my code.

This is what the compiler is printing, the first column is the start of my array, and the second one is the end. qtde is how many values are there in the array, and tam is the size of the array. The numbers in |x| are the value 'i' from the imprimir_fila 'for':

```
--------Teste--------
0, 0
0, 1
0, 2
1, 3
2, 4
2, 5
2, 6

qtde: 5
tam: 6
[30 |3|,0 |4|,0 |5|,60 |6|, 70|7|]
```

This is my code so far:

```
    typedef enum boolean{false=0, true=1} Boolean;
    typedef int TipoElemento;
    
    typedef struct {
    TipoElemento* vetor; //Array
    int tam;             //Size of the array
    int inicio;          //Start of the array
    int fim;             //End of my array
    int qtde;            //How many values there is in my array
}Fila;
    
    Fila* fila_criar();
    Boolean fila_inserir(Fila* f, TipoElemento elemento);
    Boolean fila_remover(Fila* f, TipoElemento* saida);
    void verifica_aumenta(Fila* f);
    void fila_imprimir(Fila* f);
    
//Creates the array.
    Fila* fila_criar(){
      Fila* f = (Fila*)malloc (sizeof(Fila));
      f->tam = 3;
      f->qtde = 0;
      f->vetor = (TipoElemento*) malloc(f->tam * sizeof(TipoElemento));
      f->inicio = 0;
      f->fim = -1;
    
      return f;
    }
    
//Add a value into the array
    Boolean fila_inserir(Fila* f, TipoElemento elemento){
      if(f == NULL) return false;
      verifica_aumenta(f);
            
      f->fim++;
      f->vetor[f->fim] = elemento;
      f->qtde++;
      
      return true;
    }
    
//Removes a value
    Boolean fila_remover(Fila* f, TipoElemento* saida){
      if(f == NULL) return false;
    
      *saida = f->vetor[f->inicio];
      if(f->inicio == f->tam) f->inicio = 0;
            
      f->inicio = f->inicio+1;
      f->qtde--;
    
      return true;
    }
    
//Doubles the size of the array if it hits the limit
    void verifica_aumenta(Fila* f){
      if(f->qtde < f->tam) return;
      TipoElemento* clone = (TipoElemento*) calloc(f->tam*2, sizeof(TipoElemento));
    
      for(int i=0; i < f->tam; i++){
        clone[i] = f->vetor[i];
      }
    
      free(f->vetor);
      f->tam *= 2;
      f->vetor = clone;
    }
    
//Printf
    void fila_imprimir(Fila* f){
      if(f == NULL) return;
    
      printf("[");
      int j, i = f->inicio;
      for(j = 0; j < f->qtde; j++){
    
        printf("%d", f->vetor[i++]);
    
        if(j < f->qtde-1) printf(", ");
        if(i > f->tam) i = 0;
      }
      printf("]");
      printf("\n");
    }
```

And this is what im doing for testing it:

```
    void teste(){
      Fila* f = fila_criar();
      TipoElemento saida;
    
      fila_inserir(f, 10);
      fila_inserir(f, 20);
      fila_inserir(f, 30);
      fila_remover(f, &saida);
      fila_inserir(f, 40);
      fila_remover(f, &saida);
      fila_inserir(f, 50);
      fila_inserir(f, 60);
      fila_inserir(f, 70);
      
    
      fila_imprimir(f);
    }
```

Sorry for my english, this is my first question in Stack Overflow, and I would appreaciate tips for helping me explain better my questions. Thanks for the attention!

Comment: Do you get the problem if you have a smaller number of insert and remove operations? Making the simplest test case possible would make the debugging easier for you and others.

Comment: When I run this, I get a malloc error.  Valgrind shows that `fila_inserir()` is overrunning `f->vetor`.  Tools like valgrind are essential for C programmers!

Comment: Same problem with smaller numbers, but now I realized that the value 0 showing up happens after I use the function fila_remover, that should only move foward my starting position in the array. Hey Nate, thanks for introducing me Valgrind, I will give it a try. If the fila_inserir is overruning f->vetor, maybe my verifica_aumentar is not working as it should, thanks for the advice

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not acceptable here to add SOLVED to the title or add the solution into the question itself. If an answer that was posted solved your problem, you can indicate that it did so by accepting the answer. If you've found the solution yourself and want to share it, do so by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. For more information, see the [help]. Also see [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Understood, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inserting three elements, you have `f->fim == 2` and `fim->qtde == 3`, which is fine.  When you remove one element, you decrement `fim->qtde`, so it now has the value 2, presumably since you're only keeping count of "active" elements.  So the test in `verifica_aumenta` notes that `fim->qtde` is less than `f->tam` which equals 3, and so it does not enlarge the buffer.  But `fila_inserir` does `f->fim++`, so now `f->fim == 3`, and the write to `f->vetor[f->fim]` on the next line overruns the buffer.  After that you have undefined behavior and anything could happen.

It seems to me that the test in `verifica_aumenta` should be `if (f->fim < f->tam - 1) return;`, or else perhaps you want to redesign your logic some other way.  (You could also simplify that function by using `realloc()` instead of essentially reinventing it by hand.)

I found this using valgrind.  If you're going to program in C with `malloc`, you *must* learn how to use this or a similar malloc checker.

Comment: That was exactly the problem, and now the code is working just fine. Thanks for the answer, and thanks again for introducing me Valgrind, I will surelly give it a try!